# How do I center my logo in the mobile version of Blogger?

Tags: css, center, blogger

I've been trying to center my logo on the mobile version of [**My Blogger**](http://mediatype.co), by using the **CSS rule:** 
 `.mobile.header-outer`, but it doesn't work. 
 I used `.header-outer` in the desktop version to center the logo, but it won't work in the mobile version.

Maybe I'm not using the right CSS. Could you please help?

Comment: What is your css code? Can you provide me with that please!?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Actually all you need to do is modify this seclector in `2356033831-widget_css_2_bundle.css` to:

```
html .header-outer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It makes sense, but it didn't work. Thank you anyway:-)

Answer (score 0):

`.header-outer{ margin:0 auto 70px; } and #Header1_headerimg{ display:block; margin:0 auto; }`

Comment: You are awesome!! It worked. Just a little correction to the header.outer, though, which is .header-outer{ margin-right: 260px; 
margin-bottom: 70px;} for my case. Thank you so much!!